# Best Practice for Custom Validations in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, validation

If I wanted to disable a button if a certain String(s) was detected in a textarea tag within my Template-Drive/Reactive-Driven form in my Angular application, how could I do this? Which resources would be the best to tend to regarding this information?

Comment: Sorry, be more precise. Are we talking about Angular < 2.0 or > 1.5? If > 1.5, do you use Angular Material or plain HTML-Elements? This all is important when it comes to validation.

Comment: Hugely depends on whether the form is template driven or reactive form driven. Which one would it be?

Answer (score 1):

```
<button [disabled]="isForbiddenStringFound() ? true : null"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

As a general best practice try not to mix template driven and reactive way. I would rather to use reactive forms. You only need to define you form fields as a group usin for example the form builder and add your validations with for example, a regexp. I think it is the most customizable way to achieve your goal. There are a lot of good examples on internet.